# Switch views in Xcode when a link is clicked from a webview?

Tags: iphone, html, xcode, webview, local

I have an app with localhtml inside a webview. The localhtml is basically a list with links to various sites. Is there a way to make one of these links direct to a new view inside the app? Creating a button inside the webview is not an option in this case.  The idea I had was to set the link to "switchviews" or something then switch views if the link matched. So like this (just for the concept)

```
 If link matches "switchviews" {
 Switch view
  }
```

Is the a valid way to do this and can you share the actual code for doing so?  Or is there a more effective way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) an look to the method:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

There look for the NSURLRequest to known which link is going to be loaded or the UIWebViewNavigationType which tells you what kind of action is happening right now.